# Wait untill Page_loaded in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and building a project (python + selenium). I have inserted a custom wait in code like `time.sleep(10)`
The thing i am trying to impliment is **the code should be block untill a page has been loaded fully and same after button clicks**.
I have gone through few reading like

```
implicit wait 
explicit wait
wait untill an element appears up (select by id or something else )
```

Is there any way to block the code untill a page has been loaded fully. (I do not have any condition upon which i can wait for wait untill). I can not use stuffs implicit wait or explicit as there is no fix time for completion of loading a page

```
  def run(self):
     self.browser.get('url')
     # here it should wait untill the page has been loaded fully
     time.sleep(10)
     element = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('some-css-selector')
```

Comment: it waits automattically whats the issue now ?

Comment: issue was , i put a statement find_element_by_css_selector() and it threw an exception noSuchElementFound and when i wrapped up that code with time.sleep(20) , it worked well

Comment: please see the anser

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/

> normal This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait for the entire page
> is loaded. When set to normal, Selenium WebDriver waits until the load
> event fire is returned.

> By default normal is set to browser if none is provided.

so this is done automatically as page load strategy is normal by defaul ,

But it won't consider asynchronous elements taht loads after the page get loaded , if you want to explicitly wait for some asynchronous element use explicit wait as:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"some-css-selector"))
```